# Loading WMTS raster of geoservice using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, wmts, qgis-python-console

I have try a lot of PyQGIS lines codes to try to add any layer in WMTS from Geoservices using Python console in QGIS 3.34.

Geoservice site: https://geoservices.ign.fr/services-web-experts-ortho

Layer to add: BD ORTHO® 20 cm   HR.ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS

URL: https://wxs.ign.fr/ortho/geoportail/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

I have try:

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer(
    "tileMatrixSet=EPSG:3857&crs=EPSG:3857&layers=brtachtergrondkaart&styles=&format=image/jpeg&url=https://wxs.ign.fr/ortho/geoportail/wmts/HR.ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS", # uri
    "wmts master example",
    "wms"
)
```

But it is creating a corrupted layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to know what url to use in the [`QgisInterface.addRasterLayer()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a00faa65c24cad29c2c7ad30accde4f3d) function is to manually add the layer to the legend and directly copy its source.

Here you can [create a WMS/WMTS connection](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/online_resources/wms.html) using your url:

> https://wxs.ign.fr/ortho/geoportail/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

And then load the "Ortho 20 cm" raster layer.

Finally you can access the `Layer Properties` of the layer and in the `Information` tab you can copy the source value. This is the url to use in the `addRasterLayer()` function:

> crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/jpeg&layers=HR.ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS&styles=normal&tileMatrixSet=PM&url=https://wxs.ign.fr/ortho/geoportail/wmts?SERVICE%3DWMTS%26VERSION%3D1.0.0%26REQUEST%3DGetCapabilities

The following code will load the right raster layer directly:

```py
iface.addRasterLayer(
    "crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/jpeg&layers=HR.ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS&styles=normal&tileMatrixSet=PM&url=https://wxs.ign.fr/ortho/geoportail/wmts?SERVICE%3DWMTS%26VERSION%3D1.0.0%26REQUEST%3DGetCapabilities", # uri
    "wmts master example",
    "wms"
)
```